# i need to group years and select last five years with the averages of each year so that i have average and year output

Tags: java, mysql

i need to group years and select last  five years with the averages of each year so that i have average and year output

```
SELECT AP, yr
FROM (
SELECT Year AS yr, AVG( "tbltest.AskingPrice" ) AS AP
FROM tbltest
GROUP BY `yr` DESC
LIMIT 5
)sub
GROUP BY `yr` ASC
```

Comment: OK, so what do you find to be the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: Please show a sample input data and your expected output resultset and what is not working in your above query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sub.yr, sub.AP
FROM (
    SELECT Year AS yr, AVG(AskingPrice) AS AP
    FROM tbltest
    GROUP BY yr
    ORDER BY yr DESC
    LIMIT 0,5
) sub
ORDER BY sub.yr ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your subquery does what you want:

```
SELECT Year AS yr, AVG( "tbltest.AskingPrice" ) AS AP
FROM tbltest
GROUP BY `yr`
ORDER BY Year DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I just moved the `desc` to the `order by` to be consistent with standard SQL.

Comment: yr  AP
2013  0
2012  0
2011  0
2010  0
2009  0
thanks but the above data is what i get where as AP is supposed to give me avrg of the values in millions